# Git Bash Here in Console2?

Tags: git, console, msysgit, console2

MSysGit installs a context menu item that opens a Git Bash prompt at the currently selected folder; however, this opens a cmd.exe window and I would like it to open in [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) instead.

What modifications do I need to make to get this working?

Note, I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305514/how-to-customize-which-terminal-is-used-by-the-git-bash-here-command-of-msysgit), but the answer is outdated - MSysGit is now using a vba script to invoke the bash prompt. Plus it doesn't explicity state how to get things working with Console2.

**Update: you may be interested in doing the same with [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), a [rather excellent successor to Console](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConEmuTheWindowsTerminalConsolePromptWeveBeenWaitingFor.aspx). See here: [Git Bash Here in ConEmu](https://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu)**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's what I did (your paths with almost certainly vary):

1. Create a new tab in Console with the following values:

   - Title: `Git Bash`
   - Icon: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\git.ico`
   - Shell `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`
   - Startup dir: `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`
2. Create a new key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\` called `git_shell2` with a data value of `Git Console Here`
3. Create a new key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell2\` called `command` with a data value of `"C:\Users\charlesr\My Dropbox\Software\Console2\Console.exe" -t "Git Bash" -d "%1"`

This does the trick.

Instead of doing steps 2 and 3 above, you could just copy the following into a .reg file (modify the paths to suit  your own config first) then import into the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell2]
@="Git Console Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell2\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\charlesr\\My Dropbox\\Software\\Console2\\Console.exe\" -t \"Git Bash\" -d \"%1\""
```

Comment: Just a note for others that find this later, make sure you are using the 32-bit version of Console2 or this will fail.

Comment: Note that in the latest msysgit the icon is now in C:\msysgit\share\resources\git.ico

Comment: Thanks Charles, but why run steps 2 and 3?  It works fine just doing step 1, not sure why the need to change the repository settings?

Comment: Very neat. Note you can also add context menu when clicking in the "background" of a folder (the white part, not on an icon) https://gist.github.com/4048138

Comment: I've been using this setup for a while, but it seems to have the unfortunate limitation of not being able to execute `.bat` scripts (without switching to a different tab, running plain `Cmd.exe`). Has anyone any insights on this?

Comment: Does not start git bash with start up dir

Answer (score 7):

The vba script just launches the Git Bash shortcut in the same directory; just change that shortcut to make it point at Console2's executable and configure Console2 so that it uses MSysGit's sh as its shell.

---

**UPDATED**

Going into more details as I just needed to do it again on a new computer:

- Configuring Console2

  1. added a new tab called "git"
  2. set the icon to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico`
  3. set the shell to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i`
- Tweaking Git Bash's shortcut

  1. change the shortcut target to `C:\Tools\Console2\Console.exe -t git -d .` (well where your Console2 binary is located)
  2. enjoy your new "Git Bash Here" launching Console2!

The trick is the "-d ." option passed to Console2: the `Git Bash.vbs` script changes the current directory to the point pointed by the mouse before launching the shortcut.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles upon this wanting to use
**MinGW** Bash I found a solution for that.

1. Console2, Edit, Settings, Tabs, Add
2. Title = `Bash`
3. Shell = `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe -l`
4. Edit registry

   ```
   ni hklm:software/classes/directory/shell/bash/command `
     -f -va 'c:/Console2/Console.exe -t Bash -d %v'
   ```
5. Create `~/.profile` with the following:

   ```
   cd -
   ```

[cd Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html)

This works with 64-bit and 32-bit Console2, not sure what
[coderanger](https://superuser.com/users/48147)
was on about.

Comment: There are several problems with this command that causes the console to return an error. First, `HKCR\...\command` should not be enclosed with quotes. Next, I believe by `\-d` you mean to pass the `/d` parameter to specify the data for the new registry entry. Also, you need double quotes around the data value and the `-t` parameter causes Console.exe not to open at all, so exclude that. It should look like this: `reg add HKCR\Directory\shell\Bash\command /d "C:\Console2\Console.exe -d \"%V\""`

Comment: It is obvious from your comments that you are still using `cmd.exe`, as Bash allows use of single and double quotes for strings. You should consider upgrading to Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Console2 tab named 'bash':

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\console2_bash]
@="Bash here (Console2)"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\console2_bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Console2\\Console.exe\" -t Bash -d \"%V\"\\"
```