# Git Bash Here in ConEmu embedded in Windows Explorer

Tags: conemu

I followed the answer to this question: [Git Bash Here in ConEmu](https://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu/618054#618054) and have this problem:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/fz92df.png]

When I use "Git Bash Here in ConEmu" it appears embedded in Windows explorer. If I've previously opened a ConEmu console, git bash creates a new tab on that console. I need "git bash" to open on a new Windows console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've already answered in the mailing group, that is because you've set up "ConEmu inside" instead of "ConEmu here".

Set up your integration properly and enjoy.