# Accessing gitbash commands through conemu

Tags: bash, git, conemu

I have tried to access gitbash command using conemu terminal, but I am unable to do so for some reason, it does not work for me.

I check all the answers given including this [Git Bash Here in ConEmu](https://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu) which seemed to work for most people, so I am looking for alternative.

I thought if I could click `Ctrl` + right click, then add new console and paste the link to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` all would work, but it does not recognize any of the git commands, like `git status`, `ls` ...

I am kinda new to this, I used console2 before, but now I am having problems with software.

Comment: Git was working in console2? Run the **same** shell command in ConEmu. That's all.

Comment: @Maximus No, I never used Console2 with git, just console2 alone. I've read all the blogs at [hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConEmuTheWindowsTerminalConsolePromptWeveBeenWaitingFor.aspx) and was hoping you would turn out to help me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the folder where your git.exe is located (probably `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`) to system PATH and restart the shell.

Comment: Also, it's much better to run `...\sh.exe --login -i`. Without arguments bash is not initialized for "interactive working".

Comment: @astronout, Thanks I thought it was harder than that, when I saw the git-specific configs in other tutorials. I wander why anyone didn't recommend this approach. And thanks for Maximus for creating this great tool

Comment: I have two more questions though, one the command `clear` does not work on conemu and second, is there anyway to access putty, since the above advice does not correlate to putty ? @Maximus

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" and "access PuTTY"? @Bimlik

Comment: @Maximus I meant if I enter the command "clear" on conemu it shows me this error message: "`'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`" I also found out today, that `vi` gives the same error. In gitbash I could do `vi README.md` and have the contents of the readme file edited, but not while using conemu. I guess it does not emulate all gitbash's functionality. About Putty: I just wanted to an ssh access to my centos server in Virtual box using conemu, the same way I use putty to access it.

Comment: Gitbash? Run it in ConEmu the same way you run it without. All commands will be accessible. If not - why not to find "clear.exe" and add its path to %PATH%? As for PuTTY I still can't understand your problem. Just run PuTTY, nothing special.