# How do i configure conemu to open a new tab instead of a new window, when run on the command line?

Tags: command-line, conemu

I use total commander a lot and in my muscle memory i have it that i can run `cmd` at any time in total commander, and it will open a new shell window at the current directory.

I'm looking for conemu to do almost exactly the same, only to open a new tab instead of a new window.

However conemu seems to only be configurable to open a new window on every call, or (with single instance mode) to bring the last tab to the foreground.

Are there any settings i missed?

Comment: So, what do you want to do, and what to get? Till now, from your question, single mode is exactly what do you want.

Comment: I quote myself: "open a new tab", "only ... configurable ... (single instance mode) to bring the last tab to the foreground". In more words: Setting "Single instance mode" in the configuration causes `conemu` (executed in a shell / command line) to simply bring the window to the foreground, WITHOUT opening a new tab. I need it to "open a new tab". I am baffled how i failed to make this clear and would like advice on how i should have worded my question and description above to make this more clear.

Comment: What ConEmu build you are trying? What are you trying to run and how exactly? "cmd" from total prompt? What type of integration you are using (DefTerm/auto attach)? Dozens of variants, I can't guess yours one!

Comment: Maximus: Couldn't find a version in the program itself, but the "what's new" file has this as the last entry: 2014.05.19. And the most simple case is: Have the conemu dir in PATH, hit the windows key, enter conemu.exe, hit enter. New conemu window opens. Instead should happen: Existing conemu window is foregrounded, new tab opens inside it. I have no idea what DefTerm or autoattach means, neither of those are near the "single instance" checkbox, and as far as i can tell i run the default settings + single instance set. Do you have an IRC channel?

Answer (score 7):

As I said many times, ConEmu is not a shell. It is terminal application. That is why comparison with "run cmd" is not so correct...

When you run ConEmu **without arguments**, and single mode is forced (Quake style implies it too), what must be done in ConEmu?

For example, you have pinned ConEmu on your Task bar. In most cases, pinned program (shortcut) will not have any arguments. And what must be happen when you click your shortcut on Task bar? ConEmu window must appears. But if each time you click shortcut new tab will be created... weird result will be observed. Instead of minimize/restore (or hide/restore, or slide-up/slide-down) user will get new tab per click.

So, you need to run proper command to tell ConEmu what do you exactly want. Example:

```
conemu -single -cmd cmd
```

On the other hand, there are handy features [DefTerm](https://superuser.com/q/509642/139371) or [AutoAttach](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/LaunchNewTab#Automatic_attach_of_cmd). Where to know about them? In the project [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/DefaultTerminal) of course. For example, if you turn on "Default terminal", you may just run `cmd` from Win+R and new tab will be created in your ConEmu instance.

```
cmd
```

At last, there is no IRC channel. I'm not using IRC and who will answer there? There are many other ways to communicate: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=ConEmuMaximus5), [Mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/conemu_ml), [Issues](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Issues?tm=3).

Answer (score 7):

A bit late reply but this worked for me:
In ConEmu `Settings` got to `Integration` and change Command

**from** `-cur_console:n`

**to** `/single /cmd -cur_console:n`

Then hit Register button again and Save settings.

Answer (score 5):

zam6ak's answer worked for me if i have already opened ConEmu but get auto closed if i opened for the first time. Was able to fix it by using `/single /cmd {Shells::cmd (Admin)}` . {Shells::cmd (Admin) is a one of task that you can find in Setting -> Startup -> Tasks. 
Guided from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu)

If using Cmder it's easy as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#shortcut-to-open-cmder-in-a-chosen-folder)