# Run ConEmu + Far in current folder

Tags: conemu, sublime-text, far-manager

### 1. Briefly

I don't find, how I can run ConEmu + Far in current folder.

---

### 2. Detail

1. I don't set ConEmu + Far in [**ConEmu Open Sublime Text package**](https://github.com/tianjianchn/Sublime_ConEmuOpen).
2. I don't set, how ConEmu + Far open in `ConEmu Here`.

---

### 3. Did not help

1. Sublime Text package have [**a line**](https://github.com/tianjianchn/Sublime_ConEmuOpen/blob/master/ConEmuOpen.py#L22):

   ```python
   command= "start conemu.exe /Single /Dir \""+dirname+"\" /cmdlist powershell -new_console:t:\""+title+"\""
   ```

   PowerShell run for me in current folder. If I replace in this line `powershell` to `cmd` → default console run for me in current folder. But If I replace in line `powershell` to `far` → ConEmu + Far open for me in `C:\Program Files\Far Manager` — my folder with Far Manager.
2. I try set ConEmu Here for Far [**like for Git Bash**](https://superuser.com/a/454381/572069). For `Command` parameter I set values

   [image: Far ConEmu]

   - `/Single -run {Far}`
   - `/Single /cmd {Far}`

   ConEmu + Far open for me in `C:\Program Files\Far Manager` — my folder with Far Manager.

---

### 4. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**ConEmu:**
170118 [64]
**Far Manager:**
3.0 build 4774 x64

Thanks.

Comment: After trying to resolve similar problem myself, I suggest you to try another open sourced project [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki/Downloads). It is well maintained fork of abandoned [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), and it has similar features you found in `ConEmu`.

Comment: @Alex: BladeMight solution works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is VERY simple! Just make a `{far}` task like so(basically path to your far):

[image]

and then in integration tab use these configurations to create `ConEmu Far Here`:

[image]

As you can see in image above, command `{far} .` runs far in current folder, and then it executes new ConEmu tab with `-cur_console:n` command.
Or you can even configure your *task* to run with dot as parameter: `C:\path\to\far.exe .` and then just use it in integration or even from ConEmu command line like so:

`"C:\Path\to\ConEmu.exe -run {far}"`

and it will start far in current directory, even if called from explorer address-bar.

Comment: BladeMight, I make an actions as in your answer → I run Far + ConEmu in a folder → [**result**](http://i.imgur.com/2jzw7h3.png). I press `Ctrl+O` → [**result**](http://i.imgur.com/DIUrfcB.png). How I can get result as in image 2, that I can't press `Ctrl+O` every time as I run ConEmu + Far? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных По поводу Ctrl+O после запуска, добавьте этот [Macro](https://gist.github.com/BladeMight/9c4f0765c404acac16ee8439b6c70eab) в %FARHOME%\Macros\scripts. (%FARHOME% - там где far.exe)

Comment: @СашаЧерных Еще более легкий вариант, нажмите Shift+F9(сохраните настройки) после Ctrl+O и при следующем запуске Far он будет уже без панелей.

Comment: BladeMight: both methods doesn't work for me. // **1.** [**I create lua file**](http://i.imgur.com/VDDfFq8.png) → I close ConEmu → I run `Far Here` in any folder → I still need press `Ctrl+O` // **2.** I open Far+ConEmu → I press `Ctrl+O` → I press `Shift+F9` → I close ConEmu → I run `Far Here` in any folder → I still need press `Ctrl+O`. // I repeat both actions 3 times → I don't get expected behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Does pressing `Shift+F9` saves settings(calls save settings dialog)? If not then save them **after** you change mode to `Ctrl+O` through menu -> "Settings" -> Save settings, and it will save it, so next time you run it, it will have `Ctrl+O` mode enabled already. If you can't display Far's menu(its hidden by default) click with mouse a bit lower than the ConEmu tabs(e.g. at top of Far window).

Comment: @СашаЧерных Sorry about wrong folder to place macros, correct is `%FARPROFILE%\Macros\scripts`, and for wrong macro too, i updated [it](https://gist.github.com/BladeMight/9c4f0765c404acac16ee8439b6c70eab) too. Place it in `%FARPROFILE%\Macros\scripts` with any file name ending with `.lua`. By the way did you know that you can record macros by pressing `Ctrl+.` in Far, and after that save them with `macro:save` command in far command line, the saved macros will be in `%FARPROFILE%\Macros\internal`. Continues in next comment...

Comment: So for example: Press `Ctrl+.` to start recording, press `Ctrl+O` and press `Ctrl+.` to stop recording(e.g. you recorded how you press `Ctrl+O`), and then assign any hotkey to that macro, after this enter `macro:save` to command line in far and then navigate to `%FARPROFILE%\Macros\internal` and find your macro, then edit if needed(add startup flags etc.).

Comment: After far starts with `Ctrl+O` mode(e.g. hidden panels mode) it(*sometimes*) displays a lot of blank space after last command in cmd, so to fix *that* you could use plugin [run](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=776) with it use that command to start far in current folder: `far . /run cls`