# How do I set the startup dir for a new Tab using msysgit sh.exe in Console2?

Tags: git, console, console2, msysgit

My Tab Shell: `C:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe --login -i`

However `Startup Dir` doesn't seem to work, neither with `C:\` nor `/c/`.

There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/172520/git-bash-here-in-console2), but it deals with Explorer extensions. I'm looking for a way to open the tab by default in a specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your bash version does not supports "startup directory". I believe it is **not** git-bash. git bash usually located in the another dir:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

MinGW bash (in your case) does not support startup dir.

BTW, did you try [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/downloads/list) (I'm the author)? It is another windows terminal full of features.

Comment: I really did want to use MinGW bash, not Git bash. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll give ConEnum a try later.

Comment: Thought, if you need special dir on bash startup **and** it is persistent - you may add `cd /c/...` command to your bash profile script.

Comment: Thanks again. I can change `cd "$HOME"` to `cd /c/mydir` in the `\msys\1.0\etc\profile` file and it works this way.